Error while deploying Docker container on Ubuntu server via GitHub Actions
I'm setting up a CI/CD pipeline using GitHub Actions to build and deploy a Dockerized application to an Ubuntu server. My workflow file looks like this:
name: Build and Deploy to Ubuntu Server

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v3.6.1

      - name: Log in to Docker Hub
        uses: docker/login-action@v3.3.0
        with:
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_LOGIN }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}

      - name: Build and push Docker image
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v6.7.0
        with:
          push: true
          tags: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_LOGIN }}/my-project:latest

  deploy:
    needs: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Deploy to Server
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@v1.0.3
        with:
          host: ${{ secrets.SERVER_IP }}
          username: ${{ secrets.SERVER_USER }}
          key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
          script: |
            docker pull ${{ secrets.DOCKER_LOGIN }}/my-project:latest
            docker-compose -f docker-compose.production.yml down --remove-orphans
            docker-compose -f docker-compose.production.yml up -d
            sudo systemctl reload nginx || echo "Failed to reload Nginx. May require manual intervention."

The build job runs successfully, and the Docker image is built and pushed to Docker Hub. However, during the deploy job, I encounter the following error:
err: stat /home/***/docker-compose.production.yml: no such file or directory

The relevant part of the script in the deploy job is:
docker pull ${{ secrets.DOCKER_LOGIN }}/my-project:latest
docker-compose -f docker-compose.production.yml down --remove-orphans
docker-compose -f docker-compose.production.yml up -d
sudo systemctl reload nginx || echo "Failed to reload Nginx. May require manual intervention."

Why is the workflow searching for the docker-compose.production.yml file on the server's file system when the Docker image already contains the file? When I run docker pull, the image includes the following files:
> docker run -it --rm {username}/my-project /bin/bash
> ls -R

File listed as:
Dockerfile  
docker-compose.development.yml  
docker-compose.production.yml  
main.py  
requirements.txt

Why doesn't it automatically use the docker-compose.production.yml file from the Docker image, and what should I add to the GitHub Actions workflow to make this work as expected?

I don't know if this is the issue, but it seems to me your .yml file is inside the image, but docker-compose needs it in the host where it is running, not in the docker image. So you might need to add a command to fetch it in your script, before running docker-compose.

Also, if the compose files are present in the repo, it's overwrought to containerize them only to pull them back out. You could repeat the actions/checkout@v4 step in build and have them available on the file system. Personally, I'd .dockerignore them from the container build.

To address the issue of the GitHub Actions workflow not finding the docker-compose.production.yml file on the server, I made several adjustments:
Now this worked.
Copy Files to Server: As suggested in the comment: I added a step to the workflow to copy the docker-compose.production.yml file to the server:
- name: Copy files to server
  uses: appleboy/scp-action@master
  with:
    host: ${{ secrets.SERVER_IP }}
    username: ${{ secrets.SERVER_USER }}
    key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
    source: "docker-compose.production.yml"
    target: "/home/${{ secrets.SERVER_USER }}/food-feast"

Updated Docker Compose File:
I modified the docker-compose.production.yml file as follows:
services:
  web:
    image: ${DOCKER_LOGIN}/my-project:latest
    command: uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000
    container_name: my-project-api
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    env_file:
      - .env.production
    restart: always
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:8000/health"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 10s

Update Deploy to Server
I updated the deployment script as follows:
- name: Deploy to Server
  uses: appleboy/ssh-action@v1.0.3
  with:
    host: ${{ secrets.SERVER_IP }}
    username: ${{ secrets.SERVER_USER }}
    key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
    script: |
      cd /home/${{ secrets.SERVER_USER }}/my-project
      export DOCKER_LOGIN=${{ secrets.DOCKER_LOGIN }}
      docker-compose -f docker-compose.production.yml pull
      docker-compose -f docker-compose.production.yml down --remove-orphans
      docker-compose -f docker-compose.production.yml up -d
      docker image prune -f
      sudo systemctl reload nginx || echo "Failed to reload Nginx. May require manual intervention."

Navigated to the directory where docker-compose.production.yml is located, sets the DOCKER_LOGIN environment variable, and then uses docker-compose to pull the latest image.
Mannually copied the .env.production configuration, and added them on the .gitignore.
And also added compose file on .dockerignore them from the container build
